# I need a list about the currently available processors

Tags: cpu

Basically i need a list of processors (Intel is enough), include desktop, mobile, server, newest ones older ones etc. The best will be an importable format (Access, mysql).

Can it be found anywhere?

Wikipedia is not an option!

Comment: You'll probably have to crawl Intel ARK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.cpu-world.com/info/Intel/processor-number.html) site. Those are only Intel processors but maybe will be enough/

You can easily copy whole table content and paste it in the excel.
What i got after exporting to csv:

CPU speed, Family and Name only:

```
Processor;Family;CPU
number;;speed
;;(GHz)
1.13GHz-S;Pentium III;1.133
1.26GHz-S;Pentium III;1.267
1.4GHz-S;Pentium III;1.4
1BGHz;Pentium III;1
215;Celeron M;1.333
220;Celeron;1.2
300A;Celeron;0.3
310;Celeron D;2.133
315;Celeron D;2.267
320;Celeron D;2.4
320J;Celeron D;2.4
325;Celeron D;2.533
325J;Celeron D;2.533
326;Celeron D;2.533
330;Celeron D;2.667
330J;Celeron D;2.667
331;Celeron D;2.667
335;Celeron D;2.8
335J;Celeron D;2.8
336;Celeron D;2.8
340;Celeron D;2.933
340J;Celeron D;2.933
341;Celeron D;2.933
345;Celeron D;3.067
345J;Celeron D;3.067
346;Celeron D;3.067
347;Celeron D;3.067
350;Pentium Dual-Core;1.2
;;
350;Celeron D;3.2
350J;Celeron D;3.2
351;Celeron D;3.2
352;Celeron D;3.2
355;Celeron D;3.333
356;Celeron D;3.333
360;Celeron D;3.467
365;Celeron D;3.6
420;Celeron;1.6
430;Celeron;1.8
440;Celeron;2
445;Celeron;1.867
450;Celeron;2.2
460;Celeron;2.4
500E;Pentium III;0.5
505;Pentium 4;2.667
505J;Pentium 4;2.667
506;Pentium 4;2.667
510;Pentium 4;2.8
510J;Pentium 4;2.8
511;Pentium 4;2.8
515;Pentium 4;2.933
515J;Pentium 4;2.933
516;Pentium 4;2.933
517;Pentium 4;2.933
519;Pentium 4;3.067
519J;Pentium 4;3.067
519K;Pentium 4;3.067
520;Pentium 4;2.8
520J;Pentium 4;2.8
521;Pentium 4;2.8
524;Pentium 4;3.067
530;Pentium 4;3
530J;Pentium 4;3
531;Pentium 4;3
533A;Celeron;0.533
533B;Pentium III;0.533
533EB;Pentium III;0.533
540;Pentium 4;3.2
540J;Pentium 4;3.2
541;Pentium 4;3.2
550;Pentium 4;3.4
550E;Pentium III;0.55
550J;Pentium 4;3.4
551;Pentium 4;3.4
560;Pentium 4;3.6
560J;Pentium 4;3.6
561;Pentium 4;3.6
570;Pentium 4;3.8
570J;Pentium 4;3.8
571;Pentium 4;3.8
600B;Pentium III;0.6
600E;Pentium III;0.6
600EB;Pentium III;0.6
620;Pentium 4;2.8
630;Pentium 4;3
631;Pentium 4;3
640;Pentium 4;3.2
641;Pentium 4;3.2
650;Pentium 4;3.4
651;Pentium 4;3.4
660;Pentium 4;3.6
661;Pentium 4;3.6
662;Pentium 4;3.6
670;Pentium 4;3.8
672;Pentium 4;3.8
800EB;Pentium III;0.8
800MHz-S;Pentium III;0.8
805;Pentium D;2.667
820;Pentium D;2.8
830;Pentium D;3
840;Pentium Extreme Edition;3.2
840;Pentium D;3.2
903;Pentium D;2.8
913;Pentium D;2.933
915;Pentium D;2.8
920;Pentium D;2.8
923;Pentium D;3.067
925;Pentium D;3
930;Pentium D;3
933;Pentium D;3.2
933MHz-S;Pentium III;0.933
935;Pentium D;3.2
940;Pentium D;3.2
945;Pentium D;3.4
950;Pentium D;3.4
955;Pentium Extreme Edition;3.467
960;Pentium D;3.6
965;Pentium Extreme Edition;3.733
970;Pentium D;3.8
E1200;Celeron Dual-Core;1.6
E1400;Celeron Dual-Core;2
E1500;Celeron Dual-Core;2.2
E1600;Celeron Dual-Core;2.4
E2140;Pentium Dual-Core;1.6
E2160;Pentium Dual-Core;1.8
E2180;Pentium Dual-Core;2
E2200;Pentium Dual-Core;2.2
E2210;Pentium Dual-Core;2.2
E2220;Pentium Dual-Core;2.4
E3200;Celeron Dual-Core;2.4
E3200;Pentium Dual-Core;2.4
E3300;Celeron Dual-Core;2.5
E3400;Celeron Dual-Core;2.6
E3500;Celeron Dual-Core;2.7
E3900;Celeron Dual-Core;3.4
E4200;Core 2 Duo;1.6
E4300;Core 2 Duo;1.8
E4400;Core 2 Duo;2
E4500;Core 2 Duo;2.2
E4600;Core 2 Duo;2.4
E4700;Core 2 Duo;2.6
E5200;Pentium Dual-Core;2.5
E5300;Pentium Dual-Core;2.6
E5400;Pentium Dual-Core;2.7
E5500;Pentium Dual-Core;2.8
E5700;Pentium Dual-Core;3
E5800;Pentium Dual-Core;3.2
E6300;Core 2 Duo;1.867
E6305;Core 2 Duo;1.867
E6300;Pentium Dual-Core;2.8
E6320;Core 2 Duo;1.867
E6400;Core 2 Duo;2.133
E6405;Core 2 Duo;2.133
E6420;Core 2 Duo;2.133
E6500;Pentium Dual-Core;2.933
E6500K;Pentium Dual-Core;2.933
E6540;Core 2 Duo;2.333
E6550;Core 2 Duo;2.333
E6600;Core 2 Duo;2.4
E6600;Pentium Dual-Core;3.067
E6700;Core 2 Duo;2.667
E6700;Pentium Dual-Core;3.2
E6750;Core 2 Duo;2.667
E6800;Pentium Dual-Core;3.333
E6850;Core 2 Duo;3
E7200;Core 2 Duo;2.533
E7300;Core 2 Duo;2.667
E7400;Core 2 Duo;2.8
E7500;Core 2 Duo;2.933
E7600;Core 2 Duo;3.067
E8100;Core 2 Duo;2.333
E8190;Core 2 Duo;2.667
E8200;Core 2 Duo;2.667
E8290;Core 2 Duo;2.833
E8300;Core 2 Duo;2.833
E8400;Core 2 Duo;3
E8500;Core 2 Duo;3.167
E8600;Core 2 Duo;3.333
G1820;Celeron Dual-Core;2.7
G1820T;Celeron Dual-Core;2.4
G1830;Celeron Dual-Core;2.8
G1840;Celeron Dual-Core;2.8
G1840T;Celeron Dual-Core;2.5
G1850;Celeron Dual-Core;2.9
G3240;Pentium Dual-Core;3.1
G3240T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.7
G3250;Pentium Dual-Core;3.2
G3250T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.8
G3258;Pentium Dual-Core;3.2
G3260;Pentium Dual-Core;3.3
G3260T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.9
G3440;Pentium Dual-Core;3.3
G3440T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.8
G3450;Pentium Dual-Core;3.4
G3450T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.9
G3460;Pentium Dual-Core;3.5
G3460T;Pentium Dual-Core;3
G3470;Pentium Dual-Core;3.6
G440;Celeron Dual-Core;1.6
G460;Celeron Dual-Core;1.8
G465;Celeron Dual-Core;1.9
G470;Celeron Dual-Core;2
G530;Celeron Dual-Core;2.4
G530T;Celeron Dual-Core;2
G540;Celeron Dual-Core;2.5
G540T;Celeron Dual-Core;2.1
G550;Celeron Dual-Core;2.6
G550T;Celeron Dual-Core;2.2
G555;Celeron Dual-Core;2.7
G620;Pentium Dual-Core;2.6
G620T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.2
G622;Pentium Dual-Core;2.6
G630;Pentium Dual-Core;2.7
G630T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.3
G632;Pentium Dual-Core;2.7
G640;Pentium Dual-Core;2.8
G640T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.4
G645;Pentium Dual-Core;2.9
G645T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.5
G840;Pentium Dual-Core;2.8
G850;Pentium Dual-Core;2.9
G1101;Celeron Dual-Core;2.267
G1610;Celeron Dual-Core;2.6
G1610T;Celeron Dual-Core;2.3
G1620;Celeron Dual-Core;2.7
G1620T;Celeron Dual-Core;2.4
G1630;Celeron Dual-Core;2.8
G1820TE;Celeron Dual-Core;2.2
G2010;Pentium Dual-Core;2.8
G2020;Pentium Dual-Core;2.9
G2020T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.5
G2030;Pentium Dual-Core;3
G2030T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.6
G2100T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.6
G2120;Pentium Dual-Core;3.1
G2120T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.7
G2130;Pentium Dual-Core;3.2
G2140;Pentium Dual-Core;3.3
G3220;Pentium Dual-Core;3
G3220T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.6
G3320TE;Pentium Dual-Core;2.3
G3420;Pentium Dual-Core;3.2
G3420T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.7
G3430;Pentium Dual-Core;3.3
G6950;Pentium Dual-Core;2.8
G6951;Pentium Dual-Core;2.8
G6960;Pentium Dual-Core;2.933
G860;Pentium Dual-Core;3
G860T;Pentium Dual-Core;2.6
G870;Pentium Dual-Core;3.1
J1750;Celeron;2.41
J1800;Celeron;2.41
J1850;Celeron;2
J1900;Celeron;2
J2850;Pentium;2.41
J2900;Pentium;2.41
i3-2100;Core i3;3.1
i3-2100T;Core i3;2.5
i3-2102;Core i3;3.1
i3-2105;Core i3;3.1
i3-2120;Core i3;3.3
i3-2120T;Core i3;2.6
i3-2125;Core i3;3.3
i3-2130;Core i3;3.4
i3-3210;Core i3;3.2
i3-3220;Core i3;3.3
i3-3220T;Core i3;2.8
i3-3225;Core i3;3.3
i3-3240;Core i3;3.4
i3-3240T;Core i3;2.9
i3-3245;Core i3;3.4
i3-3250;Core i3;3.5
i3-3250T;Core i3;3
i3-4130;Core i3;3.4
i3-4130T;Core i3;2.9
i3-4150;Core i3;3.5
i3-4150T;Core i3;3
i3-4160;Core i3;3.6
i3-4160T;Core i3;3.1
i3-4170;Core i3;3.7
i3-4170T;Core i3;3.2
i3-4330;Core i3;3.5
i3-4330T;Core i3;3
i3-4330TE;Core i3;2.4
i3-4340;Core i3;3.6
i3-4340TE;Core i3;2.6
i3-4350;Core i3;3.6
i3-4350T;Core i3;3.1
i3-4360;Core i3;3.7
i3-4360T;Core i3;3.2
i3-4370;Core i3;3.8
i3-4370T;Core i3;3.3
i3-520;Core i3;2.8
i3-530;Core i3;2.933
i3-540;Core i3;3.067
i3-550;Core i3;3.2
i3-560;Core i3;3.333
i5-2300;Core i5;2.8
i5-2310;Core i5;2.9
i5-2320;Core i5;3
i5-2380P;Core i5;3.1
i5-2390T;Core i5;2.7
i5-2400;Core i5;3.1
i5-2400S;Core i5;2.5
i5-2405S;Core i5;2.5
i5-2450P;Core i5;3.2
i5-2500;Core i5;3.3
i5-2500K;Core i5;3.3
i5-2500S;Core i5;2.7
i5-2500T;Core i5;2.3
i5-2550K;Core i5;3.4
i5-3330;Core i5;3
i5-3330S;Core i5;2.7
i5-3335S;Core i5;2.7
i5-3340;Core i5;3.1
i5-3340S;Core i5;2.8
i5-3350P;Core i5;3.1
i5-3450;Core i5;3.1
i5-3450S;Core i5;2.8
i5-3470;Core i5;3.2
i5-3470S;Core i5;2.9
i5-3470T;Core i5;2.9
i5-3475S;Core i5;2.9
i5-3550;Core i5;3.3
i5-3550S;Core i5;3
i5-3570;Core i5;3.4
i5-3570K;Core i5;3.4
i5-3570S;Core i5;3.1
i5-3570T;Core i5;2.3
i5-4430;Core i5;3
i5-4430S;Core i5;2.7
i5-4440;Core i5;3.1
i5-4440S;Core i5;2.8
i5-4460;Core i5;3.2
i5-4460S;Core i5;2.9
i5-4460T;Core i5;1.9
i5-4570;Core i5;3.2
i5-4570R;Core i5;2.7
i5-4570S;Core i5;2.9
i5-4570T;Core i5;2.9
i5-4570TE;Core i5;2.7
i5-4590;Core i5;3.3
i5-4590S;Core i5;3
i5-4590T;Core i5;2
i5-4670;Core i5;3.4
i5-4670K;Core i5;3.4
i5-4670R;Core i5;3
i5-4670S;Core i5;3.1
i5-4670T;Core i5;2.3
i5-4690;Core i5;3.5
i5-4690K;Core i5;3.5
i5-4690S;Core i5;3.2
i5-4690T;Core i5;2.5
i5-5575R;Core i5;2.8
i5-5675C;Core i5;3.1
i5-5675R;Core i5;3.1
i5-6400;Core i5;2.7
i5-6400T;Core i5;2.2
i5-650;Core i5;3.2
i5-6500;Core i5;3.2
i5-6500T;Core i5;2.5
i5-655K;Core i5;3.2
i5-660;Core i5;3.333
i5-6600;Core i5;3.3
i5-6600K;Core i5;3.5
i5-6600T;Core i5;2.7
i5-661;Core i5;3.333
i5-670;Core i5;3.467
i5-680;Core i5;3.6
i5-750;Core i5;2.667
i5-760;Core i5;2.8
i5-750S;Core i5;2.4
i7-2600;Core i7;3.4
i7-2600K;Core i7;3.4
i7-2600S;Core i7;2.8
i7-2700K;Core i7;3.5
i7-3770;Core i7;3.4
i7-3770K;Core i7;3.5
i7-3770S;Core i7;3.1
i7-3770T;Core i7;2.5
i7-3820;Core i7;3.6
i7-3930K;Core i7;3.2
i7-3960X;Core i7 Extreme Edition;3.3
i7-3970X;Core i7 Extreme Edition;3.5
i7-4765T;Core i7;2
i7-4770;Core i7;3.4
i7-4770K;Core i7;3.5
i7-4770R;Core i7;3.2
i7-4770S;Core i7;3.1
i7-4770T;Core i7;2.5
i7-4770TE;Core i7;2.3
i7-4771;Core i7;3.5
i7-4785T;Core i7;2.2
i7-4790;Core i7;3.6
i7-4790K;Core i7;4
i7-4790S;Core i7;3.2
i7-4790T;Core i7;2.7
i7-4820K;Core i7;3.7
i7-4930K;Core i7;3.4
i7-4960X;Core i7 Extreme Edition;3.6
i7-5775C;Core i7;3.3
i7-5775R;Core i7;3.3
i7-5820K;Core i7;3.3
i7-5930K;Core i7;3.5
i7-5960X;Core i7 Extreme Edition;3
i7-6700;Core i7;3.4
i7-6700K;Core i7;4
i7-6700T;Core i7;2.8
i7-850;Core i7;2.667
i7-860;Core i7;2.8
i7-860S;Core i7;2.533
i7-870;Core i7;2.933
i7-870S;Core i7;2.667
i7-875K;Core i7;2.933
i7-880;Core i7;3.067
i7-920;Core i7;2.667
i7-930;Core i7;2.8
i7-940;Core i7;2.933
i7-950;Core i7;3.067
i7-960;Core i7;3.2
i7-965;Core i7 Extreme Edition;3.2
i7-970;Core i7;3.2
i7-975;Core i7 Extreme Edition;3.333
i7-980;Core i7;3.333
i7-980X;Core i7 Extreme Edition;3.333
i7-990X;Core i7 Extreme Edition;3.467
Q6400;Core 2 Quad;2.133
Q6600;Core 2 Quad;2.4
Q6700;Core 2 Quad;2.667
Q8200;Core 2 Quad;2.333
Q8200S;Core 2 Quad;2.333
Q8300;Core 2 Quad;2.5
Q8400;Core 2 Quad;2.667
Q8400S;Core 2 Quad;2.667
Q9300;Core 2 Quad;2.5
Q9400;Core 2 Quad;2.667
Q9400S;Core 2 Quad;2.667
Q9450;Core 2 Quad;2.667
Q9450S;Core 2 Quad;2.667
Q9500;Core 2 Quad;2.833
Q9505;Core 2 Quad;2.833
Q9505S;Core 2 Quad;2.833
Q9550;Core 2 Quad;2.833
Q9550S;Core 2 Quad;2.833
Q9650;Core 2 Quad;3
Q9700;Core 2 Quad;3.167
Q9705;Core 2 Quad;3.167
QX6700;Core 2 Extreme;2.667
QX6800;Core 2 Extreme;2.933
QX6850;Core 2 Extreme;3
QX9650;Core 2 Extreme;3
QX9770;Core 2 Extreme;3.2
QX9775;Core 2 Extreme;3.2
X6800;Core 2 Extreme;2.933
```

[List with mobile and server processors.](https://gist.github.com/mnmnc/fd8a5a0588dd30e26f62)

Comment: It's perfect thank you very much, can you get Processor Number, Family, and CPU speed only?

Comment: Sure. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you mate, you saved me from writing tons of data by hand :D

Comment: Maybe one more thing, can you include Notebook and server processors as well? Because if i'm right these are only desktops

Comment: I've added a link to a list with all processors including server and mobile ones. I've used data from here: https://www.techpowerup.com/cpudb/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you try wikipedia ?
The following link has a list of Intel Processors right from the beginning

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors

Comment: Yeah tried, as i said it's not good, i need a LIST in importale format. I can't do anything with the wiki now.